# Qt Quick, How to change the Ui source?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am currently developing an application using widgets, it works well, but I would like a more beautiful and modern interface, I intend to use qml for the interface and C ++ for logic to reuse my code and being native, I know that to load the source qml it is in this way

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

but what if I want to change the source after it's loaded, how do I do it?

Comment: Which component do you want to edit ?

Comment: You can start from the basics, the [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/) is a good point. And please come back if you have any _specific_ questions.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://forum.qt.io/topic/53248/set-default-font-for-qml-controls/6

Comment: Sorry, translation error, i want mean source, in my language fonte may be translated to font or source

Comment: @IvesTI Explain yourself better, what do you mean by "source"?

Comment: @eyllanesc qml source code

Comment: @IvesTI I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), why do you want to change the QML code? explain yourself better since your goals are not clear. Do not be so short in your comments or in your post since without any clear explanation it is impossible to understand you.

Comment: What about another call to `engine.load`...?

Comment: @eyllanesc For example, have the login screen, after logging in I want to go to the main screen of the program, and the main screen that will be an ApplicationWindow I intend to open other screens as a registration screen, I want to do the equivalent of widgets when you opens another screen using `QDIalog().exec()` for example

Comment: @IvesTI I think that you are wanting to apply your Qt Widgets concepts in QML, no, each technology has different ways of working. Why don't you use a QML StackView or QML Dialog or similar items?

Comment: qrc:/qml/qml/login.qml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you want to load QML code at runtime ?
You maybe can do that with a Loader : https://qmlbook.github.io/ch14-dynamicqml/dynamicqml.html

I you just want to go to another page or view or something else you can create this logic in qml with things like StackLayout. Can you provide more information or/and code ?